# SQL Server Restore from Backup, Just primary File Group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql, backup

Thankfully, this question is just a what-if, and I am not in an emergency right now.

But I have created a file group in my database (sql server 2008), and moved some massive data tables over to it. Leaving my websites central tables in the Primary file group.

In the event of a restore, can I restore just the primary file group, and have a working database? Or do I have to restore both file groups?

I don't want my site down for ages while it restores the 2nd file group.

Comment: You edited out my "Thanks" ?? Interesting.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the answer is "yes, you can do this".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175199.aspx should have everything you need.  However, you have to design your database and application properly to be able to do this sort of thing.  That is, will your application function properly in the absence of those tables?  That's something you're going to want to test before you rely on it.